# How to call a list when amount of indicators is not specified

Tags: python, list

How can I call list when list name and indicators are not in the same string and amount of indicators is not specified? Is there any other way than if and else? They are not in the same variable because indicator may be optional and may be changing. 
Example(when amiunt of indicators can only be 2):

```
def Function(a, indicators):
    print a[indicators[0]][indicators[1]]
```

All I need is this code, but processing 8 indicators and 0 indicators without errors.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit:
Case 1:

```
a = [[[12, 7]], [["a"], ["b"]], [[4, "p", 3], ["17", "c"]]]
indicators = [2, 0, 1]
```

And I want function to print p.

Case 2:

```
a = "I AM UNIVERSAL!"
indicators = None
```

And I want function to print I AM UNIVERSAL!

And if I misspelled anything or did anything misleading I'm sorry, but I'm a foreigner and my english is not so good.

Comment: I think you need to add a more concrete example, your question makes little sense right now.

Comment: @Trotom  your question lacks a lot of things, what does indicators and lists look like ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. btw: don't use `list` as a variable name. It will stomp on `list()` function.

Comment: @Trotom are you trying to `call` a function named `list` and pass it a variable number of arguments/parameters?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Do you mean `indeces` instead of indicators?  It sounds like what you are labelling `indicators` here are simply the indeces of a multi-dimensional vector, one which you don't know the number of dimensions.  Is that correct?  Being more verbose/offering more code will help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking "How do I refactor this so it works for an `indicators` list of any size?"

```
def Function(list, indicators):
    if len(indicators) == 1: return list[indicators[0]]
    if len(indicators) == 2: return list[indicators[0]][indicators[1]]
    if len(indicators) == 3: return list[indicators[0]][indicators[1]][indicators[2]]
    if len(indicators) == 4: return list[indicators[0]][indicators[1]][indicators[2]][indicators[3]]
    #etc forever
```

You can use a `for` loop to iteratively apply indexing.

```
def Function(list, indicators):
    x = list
    for index in indicators:
        x = x[index]
    return x
```

---

(Incidental style tip: consider a different name for `list`, since that is already the name of a built-in value)

Comment: Can this be done as one expression and without using additional variables? Close to this: `a = [12, 6, [7, "v"]]; i = [2, 1]; print a[i[j] for j in range(len(a[2]))]`

Comment: Not with a list comprehension, you can't. How about `reduce(lambda x,y: x[y], indicators, a)`? (you'll need to import `reduce` from `functools` if you're using Python 3)

Comment: It almost does the job, but `reduce()` returns value of given element, when I want to change value of this element.